# Is there a way to collect pytest results of multiple runs in a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pytest

I have a system that sometimes has errors while booting which is what I test with pytest. I want to collect the results in a csv file such that I can analyse the results of all the runs easily afterwards. If the boot failed I would like to get the result of the first test case which failed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very long but complete solution (Python 3 only!) which does exactly what I described above. It does so be using the `conftest.py` in pyest.  It includes error handling for the case that the tests differ from the previously run tests in which case the csv file would be broken (different header). The header of the csv file will be auto-generated if it doesn't exist.

This script appends the result of every pytest run to the csv file. This is done after all tests have run. The first error message is recorded in `test_results['first_error_message']`.

Please read the code before running it. Remember to override `statistics_csv_path` which is the csv file where the test results will be stored.

```py
import os
import logging
import csv
import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict

import pytest

failed = False
test_results = None


def get_current_test():
    """Just a helper function to extract the current test"""
    full_name = os.environ.get('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST').split(' ')[0]
    test_file = full_name.split("::")[0].split('/')[-1].split('.py')[0]
    test_name = full_name.split("::")[1]

    return full_name, test_file, test_name


def pytest_configure(config):
    """Called when pytest is starting and before running any tests."""
    global test_results
    test_results = OrderedDict()
    test_results['time'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # Initial state is success, only change on failure
    test_results['state'] = "Success"
    test_results['first_error_message'] = ""
    test_results['amount_of_failed_tests'] = 0


def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    """Called when pytest is about to end. Can be used to print the result dict or 
    to pipe the data into a file"""

    create_first_line = False
    line_to_be_written = list(test_results.values())
    csv_header = list(test_results.keys())

    try:
        with open(statistics_csv_path) as statistics_csv:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(statistics_csv)
            header = next(csv_reader)
            if header is not None:
                for i in range(len(csv_header)):
                    try:
                        if header[i] != csv_header[i]:
                            logger.critical(f"Non matching header column in the csv file: {header[i]} != {csv_header[i]}!!!!")
                            raise Exception("Probably the csv format of your tests have changed.. please fix!")
                    except IndexError:
                        raise Exception("Probably the csv format of your tests have changed.. please fix!")
            else:
                create_first_line = True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        create_first_line = True

    with open(statistics_csv_path, 'a+', newline='') as statistics_csv:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(statistics_csv)
        if create_first_line:
            csv_writer.writerow(csv_header)
        csv_writer.writerow(line_to_be_written)


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    """The actual wrapper that gets called before and after every test"""

    global test_results
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    if rep.when == "call":
        full_name, test_file, test_name = get_current_test()
        test_name_msg = f"{test_name}_msg"

        if rep.failed:
            test_results['state'] = "Failure"
            test_results['amount_of_failed_tests'] += 1
            test_results[test_name] = f"Failure"            
            test_results[test_name_msg] = f"{call.excinfo.typename} - {call.excinfo.value}"

            if test_results['first_error_message'] == "":
                test_results['first_error_message'] = test_results[test_name_msg]

        else:
            test_results[test_name] = "Success"
            test_results[test_name_msg] = f""
```

Answer (score 2):

Following matt3o answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61526655/5351910 and making some modifications and solving some issues i created a report that only writes the errors:

```
import os
import csv
import pytest

statistics_csv_path = 'test_result.csv'


def get_current_test():
    """Just a helper function to extract the current test"""
    full_name = os.environ.get('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST').split(' ')[0]
    test_file = full_name.split("::")[0].split('/')[-1].split('.py')[0]
    test_name = full_name.split("::")[1]

    return full_name, test_file, test_name


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    """The actual wrapper that gets called before and after every test"""
    single_result = []
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    if rep.when == "call":
        full_name, test_file, test_name = get_current_test()
        single_result.append(test_file)
        single_result.append(test_name)

        if rep.outcome == "failed":
            single_result.append("FAILED")
            single_result.append(f"{call.excinfo.typename} - {call.excinfo.value}")

            csv_header = ['test_file', 'test_name', 'state', 'message']
            create_first_line = False
            try:
                with open(statistics_csv_path) as statistics_csv:
                    csv_reader = csv.reader(statistics_csv)
                    header = next(csv_reader)
                    if header is None:
                        create_first_line = True
            except FileNotFoundError:
                create_first_line = True

            with open(statistics_csv_path, 'a+', newline='') as statistics_csv:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(statistics_csv)
                if create_first_line:
                    csv_writer.writerow(csv_header)
                csv_writer.writerow(single_result)
```